# FCM javascript error when using https url - Failed to register a ServiceWorker

Tags: javascript, http, ssl, https

I have implemented FCM for web using this fcm documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client

Now, Everything'll be fine, I get normal notification on my web client if I set url like : 'http' I have no error. But when I set url: 'https', I get error following error:

> "Failed to register a ServiceWorker: An SSL certificate error occurred
>   when fetching the script."
>    code: "messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration" "Messaging: We
>   are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register
>   a ServiceWorker: An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the
>   script. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration)."

Can anyone show me how to fix this error?